# sort negative value in Unix

Tags: unix, sorting, negative-number

I have a problem when i want to sort a file like this

```
ce point de l ordre du jour -0.000000004070935
au sein de la commission des libertés 0.000000004017626
du conseil de sécurité de l onu -0.000000003909216
```

I try with this command

```
sort -ngk8r file1 > file2
```

but i get this

```
ce point de l ordre du jour -0.000000004070935
au sein de la commission des libertés 0.000000004017626
du conseil de sécurité de l onu -0.000000003909216
```

As you see the file is not sorted

Comment: On Mac OS X, I get different results from `-k8rng` and `-ngk8r`.  Try separating the arguments a bit, or at least putting the ordering options after the key definition (or in a separate argument from the key definition).

Comment: You may have some problem with the accents *à la française* ... Maybe you should choose a solution [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222810/sorting-on-the-last-field-of-a-line) that sorts via Perl based on last field (and that would allow any text before the number)

Answer (score 1):

I found joy by dropping the `-g`

```
$ sort -gnrk8 file1
sort: options `-gn' are incompatible
```

Example

```
$ sort -nrk8 file1
au sein de la commission des libertés 0.000000004017626
du conseil de sécurité de l onu -0.000000003909216
ce point de l ordre du jour -0.000000004070935
```