# Sorting lines and removing all but one line based on the last string?

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, sed

searching for a solution to my problem I found this thread: [Sorting on the last field of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222810/sorting-on-the-last-field-of-a-line)

I used some solutions for sorting using `sed` and `awk` and they work, one more thing I need is to delete all but one line based on last string in a line.

Example, I have:

```
www.site.com/324242_1234
www.site.com/233_1234
www.site.com/45357_1234
www.site.com/6545_2345
www.site.com/5433_2345
www.site.com/87745_456
www.site.com/453209_456
www.site.com/1345_456
```

Need this result:

```
www.site.com/324242_1234
www.site.com/6545_2345
www.site.com/87745_456
```

So I need to keep only one line that contains that last string, in this example they are separated by underline. I appreciate help.

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and, on StackOverflow, many people don't like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sort -t_ -u -k2 file

www.site.com/324242_1234
www.site.com/6545_2345
www.site.com/87745_456
```

assumes there are no preceding underscores.

`awk` solution can be

```
$ awk -F_ '!a[$NF]++' file

www.site.com/324242_1234
www.site.com/6545_2345
www.site.com/87745_456
```

**Explanation** After setting the field delimiter, `$NF` refers to the last field, `a[$NF]++` counts the occurrences of each value starting with zero.  `!a[$NF]++` negates the value, so it will only be true when the count is zero, which is the first instance of the key value looked.  This site has many examples of this `awk` idiom.

Comment: please explain the cryptic `awk` script

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
cat file | sed -e 's/_/\t/gi' | sort -uk 2,2 | sed -e 's/\t/_/gi'
```

Where **file** has the strings

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F[_/] '{print $NF,$(NF-1),$0}' input_file |sort -r -nk2,1   |awk '!a[$1]++{gsub($1FS$2,"");gsub(/^ /,"");print}'
www.site.com/87745_456
www.site.com/6545_2345
www.site.com/45357_1234
```