# Awk sort by last column and the print the whole line

Tags: awk

How to sort by the `$NF|"sort -u"` and then print the whole line

### Raw_data:

```
column1                 COlumn2                 column3
ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0001 1.46 Jul 25 2019 I42 v2.14 (09/05/2019)  ov0001
ov0001 1.45 Jun 27 2019 I42 v2.32 (03/09/2020)  ov0001
ov0001 1.45 Jun 27 2019 I42 v2.32 (03/09/2020)  ov0001
ov0001 1.45 Jun 27 2019 I42 v1.26 (11/14/2017)  ov0001
ov0001 1.35 Aug 14 2018 I42 v1.42 (06/20/2018)  ov0001
ov0001 1.35 Aug 14 2018 I42 v1.42 (06/20/2018)  ov0001
ov0001 1.35 Aug 14 2018 I42 v1.42 (06/20/2018)  ov0001
```

### Tried:

trying below but did not work.

```
$ awk '{print $NF;$0}' hwversion
```

OR

```
$ awk '{if (print $NF|"sort -u"), print $0}' hwversion
```

### Expected:

```
ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0001 1.46 Jul 25 2019 I42 v2.14 (09/05/2019)  ov0001
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, please do add sample of expected output too to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, i have added the same.

Comment: for last column sorting with unique elements try like :`awk !arr[$NF]++' Input_file`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, thank you so much,  can we sort by first `$NF` and then `column2`  as  column 2 having some different values for the same `$NF` name.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15677850/12957340) provides an alternative (`awk '{print $NF,$0}' hwversion | sort -uk1,1 | cut -f2- -d' '`). To sort by column 1 and 2, `awk '{print $NF,$0}' hwversion | sort -uk1,3 | cut -f2- -d' '`

Comment: @jared_mamrot, i saw that answer but its not purely on the awk then

Comment: @kulfi, just 1 more confirmation, lets say you have `1.35 ov0001` in 2nd and last field respectively so you want to keep both those lines OR keeping only unique lines with respect to 2nd and last field of lines? Please confirm once.

Comment: Wnat to keep both , sorry for not making that clear in the post

Comment: @anubhava, this is craziness of the people , without saying anything they will down vote because they smell it differently

Comment: Thank you all for your nice answers and comments , more powers to your teachings  help.

Comment: Since $1 and $NF are always identical (other than in the header line) does it matter which one you sort by?

Comment: @EdMorton, not much.

Comment: If it doesn't matter at all then it's much easier to tell `sort` to use a known field number (`$1`) than an unknown one (`$NF` = whatever is at the end of the line). When you want to do anything using "whatever field as at the end of the line" it makes things much more complicated since most tools don't have a "field at the end of the line" variable so then you need to involve awk, for example, to identify that field for the tool you REALLY want to use to be able to do so. It's asking to sort by $NF instead of $1 that's led to all of the relatively complex solutions you got.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a `gnu-awk` command to get this in single command:

```sh
awk 'NR > 1 && (!($NF in map) || $2 > map[$NF]) {map[$NF] = $2; rec[$NF] = $0}
END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"; for (i in rec) print rec[i]}' file

ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0001 1.46 Jul 25 2019 I42 v2.14 (09/05/2019)  ov0001
```

You can get header row as well if you want:

```sh
awk 'NR == 1 {print; next} !($NF in map) || $2 > map[$NF] {map[$NF] = $2; rec[$NF] = $0}
END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"; for (i in rec) print rec[i]}' file

column1                 COlumn2                 column3
ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0001 1.46 Jul 25 2019 I42 v2.14 (09/05/2019)  ov0001
```

Answer (score 6):

With your shown samples, please try following. This will get maximum value of 2nd column based on last column, it will also keep multiple occurrences of 2nd column with same last column(in case maximum value in 2nd field is same for more than 1 line with respect to last column).

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  arr[$NF]=(arr[$NF]>=$2?arr[$NF]:$2)
  val[$NF,$2]=(val[$NF,$2]?val[$NF,$2] ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  for(key in arr){
    print val[key,arr[key]] | "sort -k" NF "r"
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Nice, but includes all unique records instead of just the unique records based on the last field `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I thought OP is looking for uniqueness based on 2nd and 9th fields in comments, let me re-read once :)

Comment: I almost did that too, then re-read and I looked at what was *Expected* and figured it must just be the last field `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yeah, I have now checked with OP to clarify on that sir, lets see what OP says.

Comment: `for(key in arr)` will not be sorted order

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you sir, I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the number of fields, just sort on the last field.

```sh
sort -u -k9,9 hwversion
```

If you don't know the number of fields, but expect it to be consistent, you can get Awk to print the number of fields, and use that.

```sh
nfields=$(awk 'NR==2 { print NF; exit }' hwversion)
sort -u -k"$nfields,$nfields" hwversion
```

I skipped to the *second* line because the first seems to have the wrong number of labels.  If you want to force that line to be the first one, extract it separately.

```sh
head -n 1 hwversion >sorted
tail -n +1 hwversion | sort -u -k9,9 hwversion >>sorted
```

Answer (score 3):

Or a slightly different pipeline that uses the `NF` for the *keydef* for `sort`:

```
tail -n+2 file | sort -u -k$(awk 'FNR!=1{print NF; exit}' file)r
```

**Output**

```
ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0001 1.46 Jul 25 2019 I42 v2.14 (09/05/2019)  ov0001
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this is all you really need:

```
$ tail -n +2 file | sort -k1,1r -u
ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0001 1.46 Jul 25 2019 I42 v2.14 (09/05/2019)  ov0001
```

or if you wanted the header line too then:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>1), $0}' file | sort -k1,1n -k2,2r -u | cut -f2-
column1                 COlumn2                 column3
ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0001 1.46 Jul 25 2019 I42 v2.14 (09/05/2019)  ov0001
```

and if you HAD to use $NF to sort on instead of just using the value duplicated in $1 then:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print (NR>1), $NF, $0}' file | sort -k1,1n -k2,2r -u | cut -f3-
column1                 COlumn2                 column3
ov0002 1.40 Feb 05 2019 I42 v2.04 (04/18/2019)  ov0002
ov0001 1.46 Jul 25 2019 I42 v2.14 (09/05/2019)  ov0001
```

The above use mandatory POSIX tools in any shell.