# Sort list of files in different directories with zsh

Tags: zsh

Assume I have the following directory/file structure

```
dirA/1fileAA.zsh
dirA/99fileAB.zsh
dirB/2fileBA.zsh
dirB/50fileBB.zsh
dirB/subdirA/20fileBAA.zsh
```

which I want to have ordered by the numbers the filenames begin with, ignoring any directories, so I get

```
dirA/1fileAA.zsh
dirB/2fileBA.zsh
dirB/subdirA/20fileBAA.zsh
dirA/99fileAB.zsh
dirB/50fileBB.zsh
```

using just built-in `zsh` functionality.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I could think of rewriting strings sort and write them back?
Or better try to create an associated array and sort by keys?

I'm still a `zsh` and want to avoid digging into the wrong direction, too much.

Comment: Sometimes the term 'built-in' is misinterpreted. Do you need a pure `zsh` script, with no outside executables (e.g. `awk`, `sort`)? Or do you need something that will work in a standard `zsh` environment that uses readily available utilities?  For the latter case, the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3222810/9307265) may be helpful.

Comment: Pure `zsh` is preferred as I want to use this in many different environments and where only `zsh` is guaranteed to be available (as it is the user's shell). Your answer fits it quite well. Thanks!

Comment: @TobiasMüller : While zsh does have limited sorting capabilitys on arrays, the keys in your associative array would be just the numbers (because you need numeric sort, not string sort). But if you have two different file numbers with the same numeric prefix, this association gets  lost. I would therefore create a file, where each line contains just that number, and after a space is the path name of the associated file, and then use the external `sort` utility.

Comment: I wonder what environments you are thinking, where you have only zsh, but none of the standard utilities in /usr/bin available....

Comment: @user1934428: In some contexts it's easier to specify and test against a specific shell; here the "bill of materials" / testing specification is just `zsh 5.8` and not 'zsh x and awk y and sort z'. This ended up being surprisingly compact in zsh (but I have no idea how well zsh's sort will perform with large lists).

Comment: @Gairfowl: Depends on how large of course. AFIK, zsh sorts in memory, and assuming that it's doing some n*log(n) algorithm, this is what we get. The `sort` utility however can work with data that don't fit into memory, and also has the reputation to be pretty efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish this using only `zsh` builtins. The function prepends the filename to the front of each path for sorting and then removes it:

```
function sortByFilename {
    local -a ary
    printf -v ary '%s/%s' ${${argv:t}:^argv}
    print -l ${${(n)ary}#*/}
}
```

With your example directory setup, it can be invoked from the parent directory of `dirA` and `dirB` with:

```
sortByFilename **/*.zsh
```

---

Testing it:

```
sortByFilename \
    dirA/1fileAA.zsh \
    dirA/99fileAB.zsh \
    dirB/2fileBA.zsh \
    dirB/50fileBB.zsh \
    '/leadslash/42 and spaces' \
    dirB/subdirA/20fileBAA.zsh
```

Result:

```
dirA/1fileAA.zsh
dirB/2fileBA.zsh
dirB/subdirA/20fileBAA.zsh
/leadslash/42 and spaces
dirB/50fileBB.zsh
dirA/99fileAB.zsh
```

---

The pieces:

- `printf -v ary <fmt> ...`: runs printf with the format string, and assign the results to the `ary` array.  Each iteration of the format string will become another element in the array.

  - `%s/%s`: the format string.  This will concatenate two strings with a slash separator.
    If there are more values than in the input than specifiers in the format string, `printf` will repeat the format pattern. So here, it will pull pairs (of filename/pathname) from the input array.
  - `${${argv:t}:^argv}`: this will produce an array alternating with filenames and full paths, i.e. `(file1 path1 file2 path2 ...)`

    - `${   :^   }`: zsh parameter expansion that will zip two arrays to create the alternating filenames and paths.
    - `${argv:t}`: array of filenames. Built using the function positional parameters in `argv`, and the `:t` modifier, which returns the filename component for each element in the array.
    - `argv`: array of full paths.
- `print -l`: print each element of the input on a separate line.

  - `${${(n)ary}#*/}`: the final sorted list of paths.

    - `${(n)ary}`: Returns the array sorted numerically, using the `n` parameter expansion flag. At this point, each element in `ary` is the concatenation of the filename, a slash, and the input path.
      The `n` flag works here because of the filename pattern; it will sort by decimal value instead of lexically within a common / empty prefix, e.g. `foo1 foo3 foo12`.
    - `${   #*/}`: Removes the pattern `*/` from the front of each element in the array. This deletes the prefix that was being used for sorting, leaving the original path.
- `local -a ary`: declares an array variable. This is used as an indicator to `printf -v` to split its output.
  It's possible to eliminate this line and make the function shorter and a bit more cryptic by (re-/mis-/ab)using the pre-declared array `argv`.

  ```
  function sortByFilename {
      printf -v argv %s/%s ${${argv:t}:^argv}
      print -l ${${(n)argv}#*/}
  }
  ```

---

Edit - a single-line version:

```
(){print -l ${"${(n0)$(printf '%s/%s\0' ${${argv:t}:^argv})}"#*/}} **/*.zsh
```

Including this simply because one-liners are fun to create, not because it's recommended. With the anonymous function, process substitution, and additional parameter expansion flags, this is less readable and possibly less efficient than the function above.